# trying to use a variable from Console app in WPF app in same solution

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

I've declared a variable and assigned a updating value to it in a console application. I've made all of this public and sent the WPF application to reference the console application. I've added a using reference to the console application in the wpf application but when I try to call the variable in the WPF application I get nothing.  The code is extremely long and complex in both applications but if posting some code would help or maybe part of it I will.

the basic is in the console app

```
string expectedwaittime = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeMedium.ToString();
```

and then as long as everything is public and references are correct should I not be able to just type in the WPF app

```
public string expectedwaittime = expectedwaittimemedium;
```

I've read other articles on here on how to do this and I've done everything that is suggested and nothing seems to work.

I'm still learning and this is still new to me so please let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Edit:
Adding the function from the console application:

```
public static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e == null)
                    return;

                if (e.CmsData != null)        



                Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.DirectAgentCallsInQueueInRing.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.SkillStatusColor.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.SkillStatusColorIsBlink.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeMedium.ToString());

                string expectedwaittime = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeMedium.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("your estimated wait time is " + expectedwaittime);


                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message))
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //    logger.Error(" Exception " + ex);
                //    throw ex;

            }
        }
```

Comment: It may be that your console code which updates the variable is not being called.  Can you post a simplified example?

Comment: so I have to call the entire function into the code i'm currently using and not just the variable?

Comment: I added the code I've been playing with in the console application to write the information I'm pulling in the console app. I am able to display the data in the console app without an issue.

Comment: posted more code

Comment: You mentioned "read other articles on here". Can you please provide the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that you can reference any managed assembly from any other. Your console program, being a managed assembly, can be added as a reference by the WPF assembly. But, the referencing assembly cannot access anything that wouldn't otherwise normally be accessible.

According to the code you posted, the variable you are trying to get access to, `expectedwaittime`, is a *local variable* in the method `OnMessageReceived()`. You cannot refer to a method's local variables by name, except within the method that declares that variable. You wouldn't even be able to get this to work *within* the same assembly, never mind from any other.

Another rule you have to follow is that the class member you are trying to access has to be `public`, unless you are accessing it from a class that inherits the declaring class, in which case `protected` would be sufficient. Again, same rules as from any code even within the same assembly.

Your specific example is a bit odd to start with. But taking at face value your desire to access this *variable's* value from the WPF assembly, one thing you could do is make the variable a `static` field. For example:

```
public static expectedwaittime;

public static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e == null)
            return;

        if (e.CmsData != null)        

        /* ... */

        expectedwaittime = e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeMedium.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("your estimated wait time is " + expectedwaittime);

        /* ... */
    }
    catch { /* ... */ }
}
```

Now, yet another rule you have to follow is that when you refer to the referenced assembly's class member, you have to use the same name as declared in that assembly. The code you show in your question, it appears that you are declaring a new variable in your WPF assembly, having the name `expectedwaittime`, and then trying to read from the variable `expectedwaittimemedium`. But that doesn't work. The variable name in the console program is `expectedwaittime`, just like the variable you're trying to assign it to.

Taking all of the above, then if you have made the variable in your console program a `static` field, then you can access it like:

```
string expectedwaittime = MyConsoleClass.expectedwaittime;
```

…where `MyConsoleClass` is a placeholder for whatever the actual name of the class in your console program where you declared the `static` field (i.e. in my example, replace `MyConsoleClass` with the correct class name).

Now, all that said…

Storing data in a `static` field to be read from some other assembly is a really poor way to approach a problem like this. If you want to be using your console program from the WPF program, you should design a proper API for the two to communicate. Ideally, you should create a `MessageReceived` event in the console program, which the WPF program can subscribe to, and which passes the `expectedwaittime` value as part of the `EventArgs` subclass for the event.

But at the very least, you should hide the `static` field, making it `private`, and use a `public` property to return the value. And it'd probably also be a good idea to have a separate local variable in the `OnMessageReceived()` method that actually receives the value from the `ExpectedWaitTimeMedium.ToString()` expression, and use *that* variable inside the method, using the `static` field *only* for the purpose of exposing the value to the referencing assembly.

But all of that is quite a bit beyond your original question. I just mention it in the hopes you'll take that advice as you work through this problem. This answer addresses your immediate question, and if you need additional help, you should make an attempt to follow the advice here, and if you still are having trouble, post a new question with a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, and explain precisely what's giving you trouble.